# sql how to find all week start and end dates between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns

```
start_date 03/09/2016
end_date   03/15/2016
```

Now I need all the week start and end dates between these two dates

```
week_start_date     week_end_date
03/07/2016          03/11/2016
03/14/2016          03/18/2016
```

How can I achieve this using sql query. No procedures or t-sql please.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM <start_date/end_date table> tbl1 INNER JOIN <week_start_date/end_date table> tbl2 ON tbl1.start_date BETWEEN tbl2.week_start_date AND tbl2.week_end_date OR tbl1.end_date BETWEEN tbl2.week_start_date AND tbl2.week_end_date`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552419/how-to-get-a-list-of-week-start-date-monday-and-end-date-sunday-between-two

Comment: I think tbl2 doesn't exist

Comment: Easy if you got a calendar table :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql how to split a row into multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995915/sql-how-to-split-a-row-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to find all dates between @start_date and @end_date :

```
declare @start_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime
set @start_date='03/09/2016'
set @end_date='03/15/2016'
;
WITH dates AS (
SELECT @start_date AS dt
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
FROM dates s
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= @end_date)
```

**result:**

```
2016-03-09 00:00:00.000
2016-03-10 00:00:00.000
2016-03-11 00:00:00.000
2016-03-12 00:00:00.000
2016-03-13 00:00:00.000
2016-03-14 00:00:00.000
2016-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

second you need to find out weekday ,'2' is Monday `week_start_date`
'6' is friday `week_end_date`

```
select DATEPART(dw,'03/11/2016') -- friday =6
select DATEPART(dw,'03/14/2016') --- monday =2
```

here is the final query:

```
declare @start_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime
set @start_date='03/01/2016'
set @end_date='03/31/2016'
;
WITH sample AS (
SELECT @start_date AS dt
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
FROM sample s
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= @end_date)
, dayofWeekTemp as(
SELECT Cast(DATEPART(dw,s.dt) as int) dayOfWeekValue , s.dt dateValue
FROM sample s)
select Case when dayOfWeekValue =6 then 'End of week' when dayOfWeekValue=2  then 'Start of week' End,dateValue from dayofWeekTemp
where dayOfWeekValue=2 Or dayOfWeekValue=6
```

**Results**

```
End of week     2016-03-04 00:00:00.000
Start of week   2016-03-07 00:00:00.000
End of week     2016-03-11 00:00:00.000
Start of week   2016-03-14 00:00:00.000
End of week     2016-03-18 00:00:00.000
Start of week   2016-03-21 00:00:00.000
End of week     2016-03-25 00:00:00.000
Start of week   2016-03-28 00:00:00.000
```