# How to get weeks between two dates using calendar table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table `table1` with two columns

```
start_date end_date
03/09/2016 03/15/2016
```

Now I need all the week start and end dates between these two dates

```
week_start_date     week_end_date
03/07/2016          03/11/2016
03/14/2016          03/18/2016
```

I have the `calendar` table with dates and week start and enddates from jan 11.
I am trying to join with it, but its not producing the desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.START_DATE, r.END_DATE, c.week_start_date, c.week_end_date
FROM [table1] AS r
LEFT JOIN [Calendar] AS c
  ON c.week_start_date BETWEEN r.WEEK_START_DATE AND r.WEEK_END_DATE
```

How can I achieve this using sql query. No procedures or t-sql please or variables.

Comment: no `t-sql`?? - you realise that's the particular variant of `ansi-sql` used in SQL server, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql how to find all week start and end dates between two date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998691/sql-how-to-find-all-week-start-and-end-dates-between-two-date)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question 3 times

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the logic in the `on` clause:

```
select distinct r.START_DATE, r.END_DATE, c.week_start_date,c .week_end_date
from table1 r join
     calendar c
     on c.week_start_date <= r.end_date and
        c.week_end_date >= r.start_date;
```

Notes:

- The `select distinct` should be unnecessary (unless the calendar table is by day).
- The `left join` is unnecessary.